# Excel: If vlookup returns specific text, countifs number of instances (multiple)

Tags: excel, nested, vlookup

First post, but I am stuck and was hoping for some help. What I am trying to do is use a nested IF formula to determine whether the value returned by a VLOOKUP matches specific text on another sheet in the same workbook. If it does, to then use the COUNTIFS function to determine the sum of instances that specific text contained in a specific cell appears on another sheet (also in the same workbook).

One part of these formulas seems to work, but when I combine it with others, it errors and I can't figure out why.

It's probably something simple, but I'd appreciate any help. Here's the part that seems to "work"

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3,'Sheet1'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="All",

(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$U:$U,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")
+
(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$R:$R,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")))
```

If I put one more parenthesis, it works as is, but seems to omit some of the "All" Vlookup results... thus why I put works in quotations above. That might be an issue with my spreadsheet though, but felt I should include in case I'm just being idiotic. Regardless, when I input two additional IF statements, it errors.

The final formula I've crafted looks like this (double spaced for ease of reading only):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3,'Sheet1'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="All",

(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$U:$U,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")
+
(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$R:$R,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")))),

IF((VLOOKUP($A3,'Sheet1'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="One",

(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$U:$U,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")),

IF((VLOOKUP($A3,'Sheet1'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="Two",

(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$R:$R,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY"),

IF((VLOOKUP($A3,'Sheet1'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="Three",

(COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!$U:$U,'Sheet3'!$A3,'Sheet2'!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")),"0"))
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Ryan Olson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cleaned up some bracketing. Let me know how it goes as I didn't alter the formula otherwise.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="All",
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$U:$U,Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")+(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$R:$R,Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY")),
IF(VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="One",
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$U:$U,Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY"),
IF(VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="Two",
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$R:$R,Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY"),
IF(VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$B:$D,3,FALSE)="Three",
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$U:$U,Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$C:$C,"MM/DD/YYYY"),"0"))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was beating my head against a wall trying to figure out why it wasn't working. You saved me a ton of time.